# HDDs identifier (sd*) changes without reboot on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hard-disk

I have 4 Seagate HDDs connected to my Raspberry Pi through Radxa's Quad Sata Hat. After booting, the Pi correctly recognizes four HDDs and assign them as `sda` to `sdd`.

```
pi@rhadamanthus:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdb           8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdc           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdd           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk 
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
```

Then, I run `sudo mdadm -Cv -c64 -l5 -n4 /dev/md0 /dev/sd{a,b,c,d}` țo start a raid 5, which is also successful.

```
pi@rhadamanthus:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk  
`-md0         9:0    0 10.9T  0 raid5 
sdb           8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk  
`-md0         9:0    0 10.9T  0 raid5 
sdc           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk  
`-md0         9:0    0 10.9T  0 raid5 
sdd           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk  
`-md0         9:0    0 10.9T  0 raid5 
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk  
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part  /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part  /
```

At this point, I could even mount md0 and setup samba to share files, BUT, seemingly out of no where, `md0` would cease to exist. If I check the disks, the names assigned to them are changed.

```
pi@rhadamanthus:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc           8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdd           8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sde           8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk 
sdf           8:80   0  3.7T  0 disk 
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
```

After checking `sudo blkid` for `UUID_SUB`, it seems that `sda` became `sde`, and b became f. I tried multiple times and all yielded the same result. Then I tried to use `parted` to make partition for the HDDs and run raid 5 on `sda1` to `sdd1`, it's the same but this time the partitions' name changed with the disks and became `sdc1` all the way to `sdf1`, which makes `md0` still working but as a "read-only partition", although I doubt I could actually read anything from it because it has two disks missing.

I can rule out the possibility of HDD goes offline due to power shortage because I use a 200W ATX power supply to directly power the disks, power is not even routed through Raspberry Pi and only the 7p data transfer cable connects HDDs to Pi. And in between boots, the `sd*` naming is consistent with `PTUUID` when checked with `sudo blkid`

I'm really confused by this behaviour, if anyone can shed some light on the issue I would really appreciate it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To really rule out the possibility of HDD going offline (or at least some part in the chain resetting), check `dmesg`. Because that's the likely cause. I didn't tell it was because of power shortage though.

Comment: Also in advance, you should not use directly /dev/sda sdb sdc etc. but `/dev/disk/by-*/somethingunique` (probably by-id or by-path) to avoid random order in detection and have something deterministic.